# Edit SharedPreferences value?

Tags: android

I have problem understanding shared preferences. I have activity where user will insert password, start price, waiting price etc. My plan was to set starting value, and than user would change that value if he wants. 
  My question is: If I create prefs in onCreate() method, how change would apply (using SharedPreferences.Editor) when every time i run application it should create new values in prefs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To obtain shared preferences, use the following method In your activity:**

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
          "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**To read preferences:**

```
String dateTimeKey = "com.example.app.datetime";

// use a default value using new Date()
long l = prefs.getLong(dateTimeKey, new Date().getTime());
```

**To edit and save preferences**

```
 Date dt = getSomeDate();
    prefs.edit().putLong(dateTimeKey, dt.getTime()).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

No it will change the previous one by key....

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-application-preferences/